# query.on not returning any result in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to validate user using below code:

```
function validateUser(adminEmailId, adminPassword) {
    try{
        console.log('email id: '+adminEmailId+' password: '+ adminPassword);
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                                                host: 'localhost',
                                                user: 'root',
                                                password: 'somePassword',
                                                database: 'someDatabase'
                                                });

        var query = connection.query('select id from AdminData where adminEmail = "'+adminEmailId+'" AND adminPassword = "'+adminPassword+'"');
        console.log('query: ' + query);

        query.on('error', function(error){
                 console.log('A db error occurred: '+error);
                 });
        query.on('result', function(result){
                 console.log('some result: '+ result);
                 if(result.id === null) {
                 console.log('user not found');
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 console.log('user found :)');
                 }
                 });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('some exception ' + ex);
    }

}
```

The last two logs which it is printing in console are -

```
email id: d@g.com password: gfdgdf 
query: [object Object]
```

It should have printed -

```
user not found 
// OR
user found :)
```

I tried verifying if SQL is running properly or not by firing this in command line:

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
```

It showed me error:

```
Command not found
```

So I updated the path by using below command:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Then I was able to use mysql from command line, but still there is no success achieved in Node.js code :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using the same query with the same values from the command line and see if it returns any rows?

Comment: Did you try returning the result as object? (In PDO you need to set that explicitly!).

Comment: @mscdex yeah I tried that and it returned: Empty set (0.00 sec), in that case it should have printed in console: 'user not found', which it didn't :(

Comment: @DOCASAREL please elaborate on: "returning the result as object? (In PDO you need to set that explicitly!)"

Comment: Did @mscdex solve the issue? Here the `PDO` one: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php. Here for ( deprecated ) `MySQL`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php. All php, sorries. Thought would help!

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://www.codediesel.com/nodejs/querying-mysql-with-node-js/?

Answer (score 5):

If your query results in no `error` or `result` events, then that means the query resulted in an empty set. You should listen for the `end` event so that you know when the query is done executing. Then you can set some condition inside the `result` event handler that you check on `end` to see if the user was found or not.

Probably an easier way to do this is to just pass a callback to `query()` since it doesn't seem like you will need to be streaming rows in this case. Something like:

```
connection.query('select id from AdminData where adminEmail = "'+adminEmailId+'" AND adminPassword = "'+adminPassword+'"', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('A db error occurred: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    if (rows && rows.length)
      console.log('user found :)');
    else
      console.log('user not found');
});
```

Also I should point out a couple of other things:

- You should not concatenate user-submitted data into SQL query strings as it leaves you susceptible to SQL injection attacks. You should *at least* escape the values, but it's recommended to use real prepared statements. The `mysql` module currently does not support real prepared statements, but `mysql2` does. `mysql2` is API-compatible with `mysql` and is substantially faster overall.
- You should probably have a callback parameter at the end of your `validateUser()` parameter list so that you can call a callback when the query is finished, allowing you to appropriately continue execution of your code. Otherwise the place where `validateUser()` is called will have no idea when the query finishes and what the result was.

Comment: Thanks for useful suggestions, I will definitely try these :)